# Poll mechanism in Silverlight without a DB

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I need to implement a poll mechanism (simple questions with yes/no options) in Silverlight, but I can't use any database.
The client says the only available storage is xml files.

Do you think this is a viable option? I'm thinking about dealing with file integrity and any concurrency issues that may arise from this. It would require locking the entire file when a user submitted a response, and the file may get big.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

PS: Lost my previous account on stackoverflow (can't understand why).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using separate XML files per user? You could serialize every poll that the user took into a separate  object inside the XML. You remove the need for locking, as users aren't sharing a single file, though on the other hand you'd have many small XML files littering the place, and it **may** be difficult to aggregate them, though it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

As an example, you could name all the files with some hash of the user's username or something, so you'd have a file like a09r0awegamogm.xml, laid out like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<poll>
  <title>My First Poll</title>
  <answers>
    <answer>D</answer>
    <answer>C</answer>
    <answer>A</answer>
    <answer>E</answer>
  </answers>
</poll>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had looked into this for a previous project, and I believe the only option for server-side data storage in Silverlight is a backend web service. You would have to create something in Asp.net to handle requests from Silverlight for voting, retrieving options, and retrieving votes. Although I  believe the best option for this backend would be a database, I suppose you could store this data in XML and retrieve using LINQ-to-XML.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities I see:
 - go for one file per user/poll and use a background service to agregate the results.
 - Fire the user's answer into a queue that is read by a background service that produces the agregated xml file with the results. But if you do not have a database you probably also don't have a queuing system...